# Добавление данных в окно

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, tkinter

У меня есть метод window(), где создается окно и есть метод, где собираются данные от пользователя и в дальнейшем пользователь добавляется в список all_users. Эти методы запущены в разных потоках, таким образом пользователь добавляет себя в all_users, а окно параллельно открыто. 
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь отобразился в окне, когда он добавит себя в список, но я не знаю как можно обновить окно.
Я предположил, что в методе window() можно запустить бесконечный цикл, в котором будет проверяться список с пользователями и они будут выводиться в окне. Это сработало, только вот после закрытия предыдущего окна создавалось новое и в каждом окне был только один пользователь.

```
def window():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x400+300+200')
    while True:
        for x in all_users:
            label = Label(text=x)
            label.pack()
            mainloop()
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать вывод данных о пользователе в окно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, `mainloop()` не должен запускаться в цикле (из-за этого у вас каждый раз заново появляется новое окно). Во-вторых, не должно быть бесконечного цикла. Если нужно повторять какое-то действие с какой-то периодичностью в tkinter используют метод `after`, который вызывает заданную функцию через какой-то промежуток времени.

С учетом этого, можно просто вывести всех пользователей в одном окне, каждого в отдельной метке:

```
from tkinter import *

all_users = ['alex', 'sam', 'bob']


def window():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x400+300+200')

    for x in all_users:
        label = Label(text=x)
        label.pack()

    mainloop()

window()
```

Если нужно убирать старое имя и выводить новое, то можно менять надпись в метке:

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle


all_users = ['Alex', 'Sam', 'Bob']
endless_users = cycle(all_users)  # бесконечно повторяющаяся последовательность пользователей

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x400+300+200')

label = Label()  # создаем метку без текста
label.pack()

def next_user():
    label.configure(text=next(endless_users)) # берем следующее имя пользователя, выводим в label
    # Если бы последовательность endless_users не была бесконечной,
    # нужно было бы еще добавить обработку исключения StopIteration,
    # происходящего, когда элементы в последовательности заканчиваются
    root.after(1000, next_user)  # через одну секунду еще раз выполнить next_user

next_user()

mainloop()
```

Или уничтожать ранее созданную метку:

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

all_users = ['Alex', 'Sam', 'Bob']
endless_users = cycle(all_users)  # бесконечно повторяющаяся последовательность пользователей

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x400+300+200')

label = None

def next_user():
    global label

    if label:  # Если метка уже существует -
        label.destroy()  # уничтожить её!

    # Создать новую с нужным текстом
    label = Label(text=next(endless_users))
    label.pack()
    root.after(1000, next_user)  # через одну секунду еще раз выполнить next_user

next_user()

mainloop()
```

Второй вариант может быть удобен, если нужно создавать не одну метку, а сразу фрейм с несколькими элементами управления. Пример:

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

all_users = [('Alex', 21), ('Sam', 55), ('Bob', 22)]
endless_users = cycle(all_users)  # бесконечно повторяющаяся последовательность пользователей

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x400+300+200')

# Тут можно было обойтись функцией вместо целого класса, т.к. объекты короткоживущие, и не хранят состояния
class FrameUser(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, age):
        super().__init__(parent)
        label_name = Label(self, text=name)
        label_name.pack()
        label_age = Label(self, text=age)
        label_age.pack()

user_frame = None

def next_user():
    global user_frame

    if user_frame:
        user_frame.destroy()

    name, age = next(endless_users)
    user_frame = FrameUser(root, name, age)
    user_frame.pack()
    root.after(1000, next_user)

next_user()

mainloop()
```

Если нужно выводить следующего пользователя после нажатия на кнопку, убираем `after`, добавляем кнопку:

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

all_users = [('Alex', 21), ('Sam', 55), ('Bob', 22)]
endless_users = cycle(all_users)  # бесконечно повторяющаяся последовательность пользователей

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x400+300+200')

class FrameUser(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, age):
        super().__init__(parent)
        label_name = Label(self, text=name)
        label_name.pack()
        label_age = Label(self, text=age)
        label_age.pack()

user_frame = None

def next_user():
    global user_frame

    if user_frame:
        user_frame.destroy()

    name, age = next(endless_users)
    user_frame = FrameUser(root, name, age)
    user_frame.pack()

button = Button(text='Next user', command=next_user)
button.pack()

# Сразу вывести первого пользователя
next_user()

mainloop()
```

Comment: У меня задача заключается в том, чтобы каждого пользователя добавлять в отдельный label, т.е. чтобы в окне вывелся весь список пользователей. Не подскажете как сделать именно это? но данный код тоже очень полезен, спасибо

Comment: Тогда просто первый вариант берите.

Comment: Проблема в том, что список изначально пуст, а когда пользователь добавил себя в список, то окно уже не обновляется